# jQuery: Best way to compare dates (strings or date objects) in multiple date ranges

Tags: jquery, date

I have this script which compares today's date with multiple date ranges.
It works as it is, but I would like to know if it's robust enough or if it can be done better way- in particular the part when date strings are converted into date object. Can it be done smarter?

The array with date ranges has to be readable strings, as they are to be maintained by non techies.

Js:

```
//An array of objects containing date ranges
var datesArray = [{
  "from": "2/12/2016",
  "to": "8/12/2016",
  "schedule": "Opening hours: 9-5"
}, {
  "from": "11/10/2017",
  "to": "16/10/2017",
  "schedule": "Opening hours: 9-7"
}, {
  "from": "17/10/2017",
  "to": "22/10/2017",
  "schedule": "Closed"
}];

// Today's date
var today = new Date();

// Set a flag to be used when found
var found = false;
// For each calendar date, check if it is within a range.
for (i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
  // Get each from/to ranges
  var From = datesArray[i].from.split("/");
  var To = datesArray[i].to.split("/");
  // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
  var FromDate = new Date(From[2], From[1] - 1, From[0]);
  var ToDate = new Date(To[2], To[1] - 1, To[0]);
  var schedule = datesArray[i].schedule;

  // Compare date
  if (today >= FromDate && today <= ToDate) {
    found = true;
    $("#dates").html(schedule);
    break;
  }
}

//At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
if (!found) {
  console.log("Not found");
}
```

[jSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ezfo860y/).

Comment: The way you're converting the strings to dates is just fine, no need to change it. You *do* want to declare `i`, since currently that code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. So should I add `var i = "",` right after `var found = false`?

Comment: Or maybe since you already have Jquery use `$.each()`

Comment: @Meek: No need for the `= ""`.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saffrons/ezfo860y/1/).

I have changed your dateformat to mm/dd/yyyy and removed the splitting by '/' bit. The code is as below:

```
// An array of objects containing date ranges
var datesArray = [{
  "from": "12/2/2016",
  "to": "12/8/2016",
  "schedule": "Opening hours: 9-5"
}, {
  "from": "10/11/2017",
  "to": "10/16/2017",
  "schedule": "Opening hours: 9-7"
}, {
  "from": "10/17/2017",
  "to": "10/22/2017",
  "schedule": "Closed"
}];

// Today's date
var today = Date.parse(new Date());
// Set a flag to be used when found
var found = false;
// For each calendar date, check if it is within a range.
for (i = 0; i < datesArray.length; i++) {
  // Get each from/to ranges
  var From = Date.parse(datesArray[i].from);
  var To = Date.parse(datesArray[i].to);
  // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
  var schedule = datesArray[i].schedule;
    console.log(From+'>>'+To);
  // Compare date
  if (today >= From && today <= To) {
    found = true;
    console.log("Opening hours: " + schedule);
    $("#dates").html(schedule);
    break;
  }
}

//At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
if (!found) {
  console.log("Not found");
}
```

Comment: @Meek: Note that the above relies on **undocumented behavior**. The way you were doing it was just fine, no need to change it. While it's true that every browser I've ever seen parses U.S. date strings containing slashes, it's still not specified and a browser could (for instance) choose to interpret them in UTC rather than local, etc. Alternately, put your strings in the only *documented* format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. But unfortunately, the specification has bounced around a bit on that and while it's clear now whether that should be UTC or local, it wasn't always.

Comment: (Or rather, it was, but it changed from spec to spec. Twice. It's probably stable now. Here are the details on the format: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format)